# Use LaTeX as a template mechanisme

Tags: xetex

We often need to generate thousands (sometimes up to 500.000) of PDF files (each PDF will contain 2 to 12 pages) based on a template mechanisme and database variables that are combined in Java.

We're using an ODT template to generate these PDF files. However, the ODT templates are not very stable and each time the ODT is modified, this might break the compilation.

We are looking at LaTeX to replace the ODT templates. There are definitely advantages. However, a simple test containing 1.500 TeX files of 12 pages is very slow. How can we speed this up?

My test was run as follows:

```
time find "." -name "*.tex" -exec xelatex -interaction=batchmode '{}' \;
```

Comment: Out of interest, how long did it take to produce 500k pdfs from odt and from xelatex?

Comment: See for methods to speed up such tasks https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb36-2/tb113schrod.pdf

Comment: FYI. It took about 48 hours to create 500k pdfs from odt. In xelatex we hope to have a similar processing time.

Comment: what are your font requirements? tex would be quite a bit faster than xetex but not really workable if you need large opentype font support

Comment: you can make a custom format so preloading all the packages you need rather than use a standard xelatex and then loading all the package files again for each document

Comment: @user3048741 Even today with an I5, a four-steps compiling of a really complex-big latex document could be a bit tedious. I cannot imagine the frustration of waiting for 1500x4 compilations! Rather that a problem of the formats, the bottleneck seem the computer speed. Superworks need  supercomputers `:)`

Comment: Really, read the tugboat article mentioned by Ulrike Fischer. It provides some ways to get the compilation much faster. Surprisingly the way to go seems to use dvi!

Comment: The 48 hour time window means about 3 documents per second. If you have an I7 processor you can probably compile about 9 or 10 documents in parallel without overloading the CPU, which means about 3 seconds CPU per document. That's not much, but it's not obviously totally impossible to achieve.